# Django: Dynamic storage folder for models.ImageField

Tags: python, django, dynamic, directory, storage

I have an ImageField in my model which I want to store the image url dynamically depending on a user session var.
Imaginary like this:

```
logo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to = 'empresas/'+codEmp+'/logo/')
```

And the var codEmp is a session variable: 
`request.session['codEmp']`

Therefore if the codEmp of a user is for example 'McDonalds' it should save the following path: 'empresas/McDonalds/logo/imaginary_picture.jpg'.

I tried by **init** but I can't finish it and I'm not sure if it'll work.

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, filter_on, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Empresa, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        codEmp = filter_on
        logo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to = 'empresas/'+codEmp+'/logo/')
```

I tried to do this in the ModelForm but it seems that `forms.ImageField` doesn't have an `upload_to` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The `upload_to` parameter may be a callable expected to accept 2 parameters: *instance* and *filename*. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield).